# Spotify request token returns invalid_client

Tags: php, api, http-post, authorization, spotify

I hope someone can help me here:

I have an application which should use the Spotify API. But after request the authorization itself, I am stuck at requesting a token. Related code follows:

```
function post($content, $url,$clientId,$clientSecret)
{
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $content);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,
    array(
        'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Authorization: Basic '.base64_encode($clientId).':'.base64_encode($clientSecret)));
return curl_exec($ch);
}
$clientId="4df42e27a76d41f9961b0952102fexxx";
$clientSecret="3088a8b6132b40dc980540880cf5bxxx";
$content=array(
'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
'code' => $_GET["code"],
'redirect_uri' => 'http%3A%2F%2Fhome.xxx.de%2Ftoken.php',
);
echo post($content,"https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token",$clientId,$clientSecret);
```

Unfortunatly, the result is {"error":"invalid_client"} and i have no idea why...

Comment: i really hope your secret is very much different from the one you posted here (not just the 3 x replaced ..., there are only ~1M possibilities to check). also have you tried `base64_encode($clientId.':'.$clientSecret)` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Authorization
>
> Required.
>
> Base 64 encoded string that contains the client ID and client secret key. The field must have the format:

```
  Authorization: Basic <base64 encoded client_id:client_secret>
```

I read this as `base64_encode($clientId.':'.$clientSecret)`